# Fade out all other UIButtons when i click on a UIButton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have put 10 `UIButton`s in a view - for in-App purchase of 10 items.

When I click on one button I want to fade out all remaining buttons.

After finishing payment I want to fade in all buttons and fade out the button what I have already purchased.

Can any one help me?

My sample code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{myButton.alpha = 0.0;}];
```

Comment: What's it wrong with the code you posted? What is not working?

Comment: Not getting your question it is too confusing

Comment: At least use the full stop to finish the statement yaar:)

Comment: Simply disable buttons in view myButton.enable=NO;

Comment: Hi i have updated my question can you take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Put this loop in the target of your Buttons

```
for (UIView* subView in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) // Put conditions using Tag Or name to check need to allow 
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{subView.alpha = 0.0;}];
}
```

you know that there is a delegate for the Completion of Transactions :

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
 for (UIView* subView in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{subView.alpha = 1.0f;}];
    }

}
```

Note : I haven't tested. do some changes according to your need

Comment: can you help me through my image